# Javascript /Angular JS Search Array object into Array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is that:

I have got 2 Array objects like that

```
var array1 = [{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoe", photo="photo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"}]

var array2 =  [{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoeModified"},{ "id": 3, "name": 
 "UhOhAnotherName"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"}]
```

I want to search if array1 ID object is in array 2, if is id 1 = 1 name will be replaced, If no exist like id 3 will be added.

The result will be

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoeModified", photo="photo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"},
{ "id": 3, "name": "UhOhAnotherName"}]
```

I try to do that but all times I get one function with cyclomatic complexity is too high and I don't want one Super Big function for that. I think that the solution is simple but I'm so blind.....
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var array1 = [{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoe", "photo":"photo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"}];

var array2 =  [{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoeModified"},{ "id": 3, "name": 
 "UhOhAnotherName"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"}];

array1.map(function(val,i){
  array2.forEach(function(v){
    if(val.id == v.id){
      val.name = v.name;
    }
    else{
      var found = array1.some(function (el) {
        return el.id === v.id;
      });
      if (!found) { array1.push(v); }
    }
  })
  
  return val;   
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: `temp = v;` only works because there is one missing in example...if there were more than one it would only push last missing one and not others.

Comment: @charlietfl, if answer helps, I should get your vote at least.

Comment: to be honest it is not a very efficient approach since you have to do so much looping.

Comment: @charlietfl, I know but here the requirements forces to do so.

Comment: no it doesn't if you map to object in one iteration and do object lookups. Number of iterations is greatly reduced

Comment: @charlietfl, I have used map as well.

Comment: that isn't my point... inside that map you loop through array 2 for every iteration of map...then possibly loop through array1 again using `some` which has to do a loop internally. On small data set not a huge deal but on large one doing this much looping is expensive

Answer (score 1):

I would make a temporary object from each array that uses the id's as keys and stores each item as value.

Then you can loop through array 2 temporary object and either adjust name or push to array 1 depending on whether id key exist in temporary object one

```js
var array1 = [{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoe", photo:"photo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"}];
var array2 =  [{ "id": 1, "name": "potatoeModified"},{ "id": 3, "name": 
 "UhOhAnotherName"}, {"id": 2, "name": "budget"}];
 
// create temporary objects using helper function below
var tmp_1 = toObj(array1), 
    tmp_2 = toObj(array2);


// go through array 2 temp object and either adjust name or push to array 1
Object.keys(tmp_2).forEach((key)=>{       
   if(tmp_1[key]){
     // if same id exist from array one, set name
     tmp_1[key].name = tmp_2[key].name;
   }else{
     // push to array one when same id doesn't exist
     array1.push(tmp_2[key]);
   }
});

console.log(array1);
 
// helper function to prevent code duplication
function toObj(arr){
   return arr.reduce((a,c)=>{
     a[c.id] = c;
     return a;
   },{})
}
```

There are other ways you could do this using things like `Array.prototype.find()` or nested loops that might shorten the code but be slightly less efficient in the long run than creating  hashmap objects

Comment: Thanks so much, that much more clean that i have got :)

Comment: I also realized don't really even need an object for array 2... just the first one...then loop over array 2 and do similar. Still short and readable the way I did it. Get used to the idea of creating objects like this for lookups...very handy